# Select pair where value of other column is equal

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I select a pair (number, number) where tabid is equal for two numbers from the following table (i.e: number 7 and 11 have the same tabid):

```
   tabid  |  number
 ---------+--------
     1    |   6
     1    |   6
     2    |   7
     3    |   8
     4    |   8
     5    |   10
     5    |   11
     6    |   12
     6    |   11
     5    |   6
     4    |   7
     3    |   8
     2    |   11
```

The result of this should be:

```
   number |  number
 ---------+--------
     7    |   11
     7    |   8
     10   |   11
     11   |   12
     6    |   10
     6    |   11
```

Comment: OK.  What have you already tried and/or researched?

Comment: What should happen for tabid `5` because it has three entires

Comment: I have edited the result table.. forgot that 5 has three entries

Comment: Why isn't 6,6 in the results both have tabid of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
select
  t1.number, t2.number
from t t1, t t2
where t1.tabid = t2.tabid
and t1.number < t2.number;
```

produces:

```
    NUMBER     NUMBER
---------- ----------
         6         10 
         6         11 
         7          8 
         7         11 
        10         11 
        11         12
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: this solution just happens to coincide with your expected result. but this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: for example 7 has {2,4}, 11 has {2,6} and they have an element in common..so that pair should show up..that is the logic here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_agg` to concatenate the tabid's into an array. Thereafter self join this cte to check if one array is an overlap of the other using the array operator [`&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html).

```
with concatenated as (
select array_agg(tabid) as arr_tab, num
from t
group by num
)
select c1.num,c2.num
from concatenated c1
join concatenated c2 on c1.num < c2.num
where c2.arr_tab && c1.arr_tab
order by 1,2
```

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/JPBD66469)